# org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Am deploying an application repair-service on Apache Tomcat server using Eclipse, but the issue seems that the application is not getting copied in the webapps folder i.e its not getting published.

HTTPConnectionManager class is already present in the jar in build path.

```
Sep 09, 2013 1:24:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/repair-service] has started
Sep 09, 2013 1:25:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
SEVERE: Exception starting Context with name [/repair-service]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component 

    [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/repair-service]]
        `enter code here`at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3926)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1271)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1440)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:301)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpConnectionManager
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:261)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:67)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:405)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5179)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 11 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnectionManager
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
        ... 25 more

    Sep 09, 2013 1:25:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
    INFO: Reloading Context with name [/repair-service] is completed
```

Answer (score 0):

Just checking, do you have the jar for Apache HTTP Client in your classpath? If not, add and try to deploy the application again.

**EDIT**
Make sure your library is selected in the "Project Properties > Deployment Assembly". Another option is to put that dependency in the Tomcat library directory.